# Promise that returns a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I am trying to create the following promise syntaxes:

I want the secondary `then` to be called after the post function, how can I do that?

```
randomBytes.then(function() {
   return requestPromise.post(....);
}).then(function() {
   // I want this part to be called after the POST
});
```

Comment: If `requestPromise.post` returns a Promise then your code should work as you want.

Comment: Can you post more code? Are you using a $http function?

Comment: This is not a "promise that returns a promise". Promises don't return anything. They call handlers specified in calls to `then`. So the correct description here is  a "promise handler which returns a promise", which as others have said, is perfectly fine and explicitly defined in the promises spec. So what you've written if fine. Did you try it? What is your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact this already works (as the comment said - assuming `.post` returns a promise) is pretty much the point of `then` - it allows you to wait for stuff.

If you return a promise from `then`, the chain will *assume its state* and thus will only call the following segments *after it has completed*.

```
randomBytes.then(function() {
   return requestPromise.post(....);
}).then(function() {
   // WILL ALWAYS BE CALLED AFTER THE POST
});
```

Answer (score 0):

it should work.
and you can add a 'then' to get the post value;

```
randomBytes.then(function() {
   return requestPromise.post(....).then((value,...)=>{return value;});
}).then(function(value) {
   //console.log(value);
});
```

Comment: The `.then((value,...` part you added is redundant. (If you were going to write such a function, you can do so more compactly as `value => value`; when you write it that way, it becomes more obvious that it accomplishes nothing.)